# Sed add line in between two characters on each line

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have a file with the following lines:

```
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
```

where `XXXX` is a number with 1-5 digits.
I would like to add a space in between `XXXX` and `O` in the last three lines, so that they match the first three. I can select the relevant part with `HETATM *[0-9]* O`. How can I add an extra space in between `[0-9]*` and `O` with `sed`? (Note: I'm using Mac OS X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `tac` to print the file in reverse, then `awk` to include a space after the 2nd field on the first three lines and then reverse it back:

```
tac file | awk 'NR<=3 {$2=$2" "}1' | tac
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
HETATM XXXX O   ...
$ tac a | awk 'NR<=3 {$2=$2" "}1' | tac
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O   ...
HETATM XXXX  O ...
HETATM XXXX  O ...
HETATM XXXX  O ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify at which line it should stop adding characters? And it says `tac: command not found`

Comment: Yes, sure, just replace `3` for the number you want. Or make it variable: `tac file | awk -v lines=3 'NR<=lines {$2=$2" "}1' | tac`

Comment: Would that change the line number it starts from? I'd like to specify a range: between lines `3` and `1200`, for instance.

Comment: Then you can say `NR>=min && NR<=max` and provide the `min` and `max` values. Take into account `tac` is printing in reverse. But if you know for sure which lines are to be affected (that is, not "last 3 lines" but "from line X to line Y"), just get rid of `tac` and just run the `awk` part.